# ¿porque no obtengo error en esta petición ajax post, pero cae en erro al recibir la respuesta

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, ajax, post

Buen día, realizo la siguiente petición ajax, utilizo laravel para entrar en contexto.

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/api/logistica/carta/guardar_editar',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                viaje: CartaCreate.viaje, carta: CartaCreate.editando, destino: this.destinatario_id.val(),
                pg: this.pg.val(), ruta: document.getElementById("ruta_id").dataset.clave,
                producto: this.producto.val(), embarque: this.cp_embarque.val()
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                CartaCreate.showLoader(CartaCreate.createCartaBtn);
            },
            success: function () {
                CartaCreate.hideLoader(CartaCreate.createCartaBtn);
            },
            error: function () {
                CartaCreate.showError('Error al editar la carta porte.');
                CartaCreate.hideLoader(CartaCreate.createCartaBtn);
            }
        });
```

se resuelve por la siguiente ruta:

```
Route::post('carta/guardar_editar', 'CartasPorteController@guardarEdicion');
```

de ahi, resuelvo por el controlador, y aqui no hay ningun problema,

```
public function guardarEdicion(Request $request){
    $contents = Storage::disk('public')->get('cartasporte/cartaporte-'.$request->viaje.'.json');
    $contents = json_decode($contents, TRUE);
    $datos = $contents['viaje']['cartas'];
    foreach($datos as $key => $value){
        if ($request->carta == $datos[$key]['folio']){
            $datos[$key]['destino'] = $request->destino;
            $datos[$key]['pg'] = $request->pg;
            $datos[$key]['ruta'] = $request->ruta;
            $datos[$key]['producto'] = $request->producto;
            $datos[$key]['embarque'] = $request->embarque;
            $contents['viaje']['cartas'] = $datos;
            Storage::disk('public')->put('cartasporte/cartaporte-'.$request->viaje.'.json',json_encode($contents));
            break;
        }
    }
    return $this->generarTabla($request->viaje);
}
```

como observamos, el return va a otra funcion, la cual la reutilizo en otra parte y funciona sin problema, es la siguiente:

```
function generarTabla($viaje){
    $contents = Storage::disk('public')->get('cartasporte/cartaporte-'.$viaje.'.json');
    $contents = json_decode($contents, TRUE);
    $datos = $contents['viaje']['cartas'];
    foreach($datos as $key => $value){
        $origen = Planta::select('descripcion')->find($datos[$key]['origen']);
        $datos[$key]['origen'] = $origen->descripcion;
        $destino = Planta::select('descripcion')->find($datos[$key]['destino']);
        $datos[$key]['destino'] = $destino->descripcion;
        $pg = Remolque::select('no_pemex')->find($datos[$key]['pg']);
        $datos[$key]['pg'] = $pg->no_pemex;
        $producto = Producto::select('nombre')->find($datos[$key]['producto']);
        $datos[$key]['producto'] = $producto->nombre;
    }
    if (count($datos)== 0){
        Storage::disk('public')->delete('cartasporte/cartaporte-'.$viaje.'.json');
        return response()->json(['sincartas' => '0'], 200);
    }else{
        return view('logistica/cartas/partials/tabla-cps', compact('datos'));
    }
}
```

El problema radica que en esta petición ajax, si yo imprimo lo que devuelve, siempre cae en la parte de error, y en error me dice que se proceso bien, llego en DONE, y el contenido es el resultado de la vista que retorno en generarTabla(), debuggeando con intelliJ hace todos los pasos bien, en el JS, cae en error, pero cae con el contenido correcto, quisiera saber algunas otras opciones de que esta sucediendo.
Al procesar la petición, regresa con este estado.
[image: respuesta de la peticion]

en consola si hago lo siguiente:

```
error: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
                CartaCreate.showError('Error al editar la carta porte.');
                CartaCreate.hideLoader(CartaCreate.createCartaBtn);
            }
```

es la siguiente:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando se hace la petición ajax, cual es el `HTTP status code` de la respuesta?

Comment: status 200OK, adjunto imagen en una actualización del post.

Comment: ¿Qué aparece en la consola, en la pestaña "Respuesta"?

Comment: ¿Qué se supone que recibirías en caso de éxito? Aquí no pones nada: `success: function () {`, prueba a poner algo así: **`success: function (response) { console.log('Respuesta desde el servidor: '+response); //resto del código...`**  y revisa si ves la respuesta en la consola. O sea, la función del `success` debe tener en parámetro la respuesta que vendría del servidor.

Comment: cae en error e imprime lo siguiente (actualizo)

Comment: En la petición AJAX tienes definido `dataType: 'json'` y desde PHP devuelves HTML, por eso el error: _jQuery_ intenta convertir la respuesta a _JSON_, pero no es posible. Cambia a `dataType: 'html'` y, dentro de `success:`, usa la respuesta para actualizar el contenedor que corresponda.

Comment: @Triby esa fue la solucion!

Comment: Viendo tu nueva edición se aprecia que `responseText` tiene un contenido HTML. Significa que desde el servidor estás respondiendo con ese contenido y no con un JSON. Como bien apunta @Triby, si has puesto un `dataType: 'json'` en la petición Ajax, debes asegurar que desde el servidor se responde ùnicamente JSON, el cuál debes recibir como parámetro en el `success` y usar para actualizar el contenedor que haga falta. Si por el contrario lo que quieres es un `html` sin más, entonces debes cambiar el parámetro, poniendo `dataType: 'html'` y mostrar el HTML donde lo necesites.